# show the list of selected id in mysql php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a list of id in my array.
These are the id of my rows that I want to display only in mysql

```
sample:
$id = array(12,13,14,15,16);
Select *from tableName where $id IN(?);
```

I want to query only the value in my array to mysql.
I try WHERE IN in mysql but it shows all rows.

How can I display the row of mysql that have the same id in my array?

Comment: can you please write down full query?

Comment: `SELECT id, name, surname FROM users WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $id) . ')`

Comment: hey, `$id` should be `$ids`, shouldn't be ?

Comment: @DhavalBhavsar sorry. I will update my post. I clean my query first because I have joins added.

Comment: If you didn't get still answer please post your query

Comment: There isn't enough information in your question for anyone to be able to provide thoughtful guidance. Just guesses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before all you need to convert your array to string by

```
$ids = implode(',', $id);
```

Hi can you please try FIND_IN_SET Like example

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE FIND_IN_SET(id,'$ids')
```

And if you want to use IN then

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE id IN ($ids)
```

Comment: If I use where in. it displays all. but i will try find_in_set

Comment: I used where in. I got it now. thanks to diego help. I add implode. Your FIND_IN_SET works for me now. thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$id = array(12,13,14,15,16);
SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE id IN (' . implode(',', $id) . ');
```